# Converting a plotted line into a model object

Tags: r, plot, predict

Let's say I have a series of points between which I want to plot straight lines:

```
x <- c(0, 2, 4, 7, 12)
y <- c(0, 0, 4, 5, 0)
plot(x, y, type = 'l')
```

[image: line plot going through the points (2,1), (6,2), (7,5), and (12,2)]

How would I go about turning this plotted line into a simple model object? For instance, something with which I would be able to use the `stats::predict()` function to do something like this:

```
model.object <- ???

predict(model.object, data.frame(x = 3))
```

Output:

```
2
```

Or, at the very least, is there some way R can identify the slopes and intercepts of each of these lines between the points so I could manually create a piecewise function using if-statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's a bit different than `predict`, you can use `approxfun` to do interpolation between points

```
f <- approxfun(x, y)
f(3)
# [1] 2
```

Note that it just takes a vector of `x` values rather than a data.frame to make predictions.